# Reading MathType MTEF Format

Tags: xml, parsing, math, cpu-word

I have an XML file containing some scientific text that I want to display as proper as possible as HTML. Within the XML I find some text that looks like a binary string, possibly produced by MathType.

An example of such a string is this one:

... are assumed to be independent and normally distributed as `(0;σb2MathType@MTEF@5@5@+=feaafiart1ev1aaatCvAUfKttLearuWrP9MDH5MBPbIqV92AaeXatLxBI9gBaebbnrfifHhDYfgasaacH8akY=wiFfYdH8Gipec8Eeeu0xXdbba9frFj0=OqFfea0dXdd9vqai=hGuQ8kuc9pgc9s8qqaq=dirpe0xb9q8qiLsFr0=vr0=vr0dc8meaabaqaciaacaGaaeqabaqabeGadaaakeaaiiGacqWFdpWCdaqhaaWcbaGaemOyaigabaGaeGOmaidaaaaa@30E2@)` and ...

Has anybody seen this format and knows how to read it in?

**UPDATE 2011/02/15:**
I should add to my question that I need to read in this data programmatically and if possible would like to convert it to TeX or similar. So the answers so far are going in the right direction but are not quite what I need to do yet. I will check out the SDK for sure.

Comment: Just updated the questions a bit.

Comment: Just found the beginnings of a Java project to parse MTEF: https://github.com/danielrendall/Metaphor (Says it does not do much yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's MTEF all right. It's highly unusual for it to *not* be accompanied by a graphical representation of the expression, or in some cases MathML or TeX. Still, you can copy the entire chunk and paste it into MathType. If you do that for the above string of MTEF, you get \sigma _b^2.

Answer (score 1):

The MTEF format is documented as part of our MathType SDK. See www.dessci.com. MathType also has the capability of reading in this format and converting it to LaTeX or MathML.