# How to use Embedded Equations in Java Apache POI library?

Tags: java, ms-office, apache-poi

I am trying to use "Apache POI" to extract embedded equation and text from a .doc MS Word file into a .ppt MS Powerpoint file, I have successfully extracted text, but how do I extract embedded equations?

the Embedded Equations comes out like this if I only extract it as text:

```
!!EMBED Equation.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not help you with the binary .doc format, but for the newer .docx format, I was able to get to the equation, which is embedded as an OLE document, using the following code:

```
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(in);
 for (PackagePart p : doc.getAllEmbedds()) {
   POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(p.getInputStream());
   byte[] oleData = IOUtils.toByteArray(
              poifs.createDocumentInputStream("Equation Native"));
 }
```

And then you can [extract the MathType data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996893/reading-mathtype-mtef-format) in there and hand it to [a MTEF parser](https://github.com/danielrendall/Metaphor).

If you don't need the MathType data, there is also a placeholder image (in WMF format) that just renders the equation.

Comment: Thank you, though I don't need it anymore.

Comment: @Thilo Could you please take a look at this question also?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418453/how-can-i-add-embedded-equations-to-docx-files-by-using-apache-poi